# nuxtServerInit equivalent in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

in `nuxt.js` we can use `nuxtServerInit` and call backend api only once for a page reload. After that it doesn't run. So its a best place to get one time data server side like getting authenticated user details and storing it in the store. After that one load, you don't have to worry about the auth user. Is there anything like this in next.js?